# getting post and likes from facebook graph api android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am trying to get the post and their likes form the facebook graph api. When I am quering to get all posts, it returns 200 status but null json object, even though I have set permissions and also query looks fine. Here is the query I am using

```
 Log.d(TAG, " jajajaj "+ MainActivity.accessToken);
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/posts",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, " FB Data "+ response.toString());
                    try{
                        JSONObject main = new JSONObject();
                        JSONArray jArray = main.getJSONArray("data");
                        Log.d(TAG, " JArray size "+ jArray.length());
                        for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
                            Log.d(TAG, " Real Data "+ jArray.getJSONObject(i).get("id"));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException exception){
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

recieved response.toString() is

```
 {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[]}, error: null}
```

permission set for the request are as follows:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("user_posts", "public_profile", "user_friends", "user_likes","user_events","read_stream", "user_about_me", "user_friends" ));
```

I dont really understand what I am doing wrong...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I’d recommend that you use Graph API Explorer first to “play around” and figure out what your request you need to make, and with what permissions.

Answer (score 0):

your code must be like following code:

```
new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/posts",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject();
       for (int i = 0; i < object.optJSONArray("data").length(); i++){
Log.d(TAG, " Real Data"+object.optJSONArray("data").optJSONObject(i).optString("id"));

}
}});
request.executeAsync();
```

That is, you create a new JSonObject which is null instead of using GraphResponse object which is sent from Facebook Graph API.